# Faster method to tile windows without admin access

Tags: applescript, window-manager

Note: I *should* just ask IT support to grant access, but they wouldn't allow the installation of an unreviewed app.
I don't have access to sudo or an administrator account on my macOS 13 machine.

I want to tile apps and windows quickly. For this, I've currently set up a few workflows which run AppleScripts that are invoked when I press some keyboard shortcuts (like Ctrl+Opt+numpad keys). But the workflows (made using Automator):

- take a long while to run (> 5 seconds for a keypress)
- don't work for some windows (eg. Electron based apps like Obsidian, VSCode, etc)

Is there a solution that is faster? And doesn't require elevation? Granting accessibility access to a third-party app requires elevation, so I can't use Raycast, Amethyst, etc

PS: here is one of the scripts:

```
on run {input, parameters}

    set the_application to (path to frontmost application as Unicode text)
    
    tell application "Finder"
        set screenResolution to bounds of window of desktop
    end tell
    
    set screenWidth to item 3 of screenResolution
    set screenHeight to item 4 of screenResolution
    set appHeight to screenHeight / 2 as integer
    set appWidth to screenWidth / 2 as integer
    
    tell application the_application
        activate
        reopen
        set yAxis to 0 as integer
        set xAxis to 0 as integer
        set the bounds of front window to {xAxis, yAxis, appWidth + xAxis, appHeight + yAxis}
    end tell
    
    return input
end run
```